# How to use query-expression for <int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter> in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring-integration

```
<int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter
        id="mongoInboundAdapter" channel="mongoMessageChannel"
        collection-name="shiporder" 
        query-expression="new BasicQuery().addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(
        Criteria.where('orderperson').is('****'), Criteria.where('status').is('false')">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="15000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
    </int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

The Above code snippet giving **Unexpected ran out of arguments** while running server

Can anyone help on this.

Comment: `query="{$and:[{'orderperson':'*****'},{'status':'false'}]}` this one is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is there that `<int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter>` doesn't support QueryDSL yet:

```
Query query = new BasicQuery(this.queryExpression.getValue(this.evaluationContext, 
                                                              String.class));
```

As you see we expect there only a `String` result from the expression evaluation.
And only after that build the `BasicQuery` based on that JSON String.

I'm sure we really can support the QueryDSL there like we do with the `search-args-expression` for the `<int-twitter:search-outbound-gateway>` and with the `statementExpression` in the `CassandraMessageHandler`.

Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) ticket on the matter.

Comment: Thanks @Artem Bilan for your quick response, I have one more question can you please let me know when we will use `query` and when we will use `query-expression` under `<int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter>`

Comment: Well, not sure right now, but that looks like you can return a JSON query string from some bean, e.g. `@myQueryBean.getQuery()`. Yes, it isn't so useful because the `Query` object would be more flexible, but there is no choice right now...